# Get "char" of a multi-byte character in linux/mac

Tags: c++, utf-8

I have and std::string with utf-8 characters (some latin, some non-latin) in linux and mac.

As we know, utf-8 char size is not fixed, and some of the characters are not just 1 byte (like regular latin characters).

The question is how can I get the *character* in offset *i*?

It makes sense to use int32 data type to store the char, but how do I get that character?

For example:

```
std::string str = read_utf8_text();
int c_can_be_more_than_one_byte = str[i]; // <-- obviously this code is wrong
```

It is important to point out that I **do not** know the size of character in offset *i*.

Comment: Perhaps you should have a UTF-8 to UTF-32 conversion when reading? So the internal representation of the text inside your program (in memory) is fixed-width UTF-32 encoding? You could use [`std::codecvt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) for such conversions.

Comment: If you don't want to use a library it isn't hard to interpret the high two bits and count characters.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I am *really* trying to avoid conversions, its going to be quite expensive in time & memory wise.... (at least in my use-case)

Comment: You're not going to be able to avoid conversions anyway, not if you want the full Unicode code point (which basically is a UTF-32 encoded character). You could do the conversion only when needed (i.e. when initializing `c_can_be_more_than_one_byte`) but you still need to do a conversion. The question is if you want to use the standard C++ facilities that already exists, use a library, or want to do it yourself.

Comment: I will check the size of the character on the specific places I need and not everything (the given "i" is guaranteed to be a beginning of a character). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, you should be aware of "combining characters" and "zero-width" characters. They might affect  your concept of "position".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple.

First, you have to understand, you **cant** calculate the position without iterating the string (that's obvious fr var-length characters)

Second, you need to remember that in `utf-8` characters can be 1-4 bytes and in case they occupy more than one byte, all trailing bytes have `10` significant bits set. So, you just count bytes, ignoring them if `(byte_val & 0xC0) == 0x80`.

Unfortunately, I don't have compiler at my disposal right now, so please be kind to possible mistakes in the code:

```
int desired_index = 19;
int index = 0;
char* p = my_str.c_str(); 
while ( *p && index < desired_index ){
  if ( (*p & 0xC0) != 0x80 ) // if it is first byte of next character
    index++;
  p++;
}

// now p points to trailing (2-4) bytes of previous character, skip them
while ( (*p & 0xC0) == 0x80 )
  p++;

if ( *p ){
  // here p points to your desired char
} else {
  // we reached EOL while searching
}
```